# How to expand existing PHP calendar class

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

Iam using a free PHP calendar class from [startutorial](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-web-calendar-in-php)

in `private function _showDay($cellNumber)` i develop a small function which color the actual day in red.

```
if(date("Y-m-d") == $this->currentDate) { $heute = "background-color: red;"; }

return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                ($cellContent==null?'mask':''). '"style="'. $heute .'">'.$cellContent.'</li>';
```

This is working.

Now i want to count all entrys in db to a actual day/date.

My mysql db for calendar-entries looks like this:

```
id | headline | text | timestamp (datum)
```

My count looks like this

```
$offen = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS anzahl 
          FROM info_info 
          WHERE `datum` > '2018-09-06 00:00:00' AND `datum` < '2018-09-06 23:59:59'";

$resultoffen = $con->query($offen);

    if ($resultoffen->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $resultoffen->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ungelesen = $row["anzahl"];
        echo $ungelesen;
        }
    }
```

My full customized script looks like this:

```
<?php

class Calendar {  

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(){     
        $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    /********************* PROPERTY ********************/  
    private $dayLabels = array("Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa","So");

    private $currentYear = 0;

    private $currentMonth = 0;

    private $currentDay = 0;

    private $currentDate = null;

    private $daysInMonth = 0;

    private $naviHref = null;

    /********************* PUBLIC **********************/  

    /**
    * print out the calendar
    */
    public function show() {
        $year  == null;

        $month == null;

        if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

            $year = $_GET['year'];

        }else if(null==$year){

            $year = date("Y",time());  

        }          

        if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

            $month = $_GET['month'];

        }else if(null==$month){

            $month = date("m",time());

        }                  

        $this->currentYear=$year;

        $this->currentMonth=$month;

        $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  

        $content='<div id="calendar">'.
                        '<div class="box">'.
                        $this->_createNavi().
                        '</div>'.
                        '<div class="box-content">'.
                                '<ul class="label">'.$this->_createLabels().'</ul>';   
                                $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     
                                $content.='<ul class="dates">';    

                                $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                                // Create weeks in a month
                                for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                                    //Create days in a week
                                    for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                        $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                                    }
                                }

                                $content.='</ul>';

                                $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     

                        $content.='</div>';

        $content.='</div>';
        return $content;   
    }

    /********************* PRIVATE **********************/ 
    /**
    * create the li element for ul
    */

    private function _showDay($cellNumber){

        if($this->currentDay==0){

            $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));

            if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

                $this->currentDay=1;

            }
        }



        if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

            $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

            $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

            $this->currentDay++;   

        }else{

            $this->currentDate = null;

            $cellContent=null;
        }

        //aktuellen tag rot markieren
        if(date("Y-m-d") == $this->currentDate) { $heute = "background-color: red;"; }


        //anzahl der kalendereinträge
        $offen = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS anzahl 
          FROM info_info 
          WHERE `datum` > '".$this->currentDate." 00:00:00' AND `datum` < '".$this->currentDate." 23:59:59'";

        $resultoffen = $con->query($offen);

        if ($resultoffen->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $resultoffen->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ungelesen = $row["anzahl"];
            echo $ungelesen;
            }
        }

        //gib kalender zurück
        return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                ($cellContent==null?'mask':''). '"style="'. $heute .'">'.$cellContent.'</li>';
    }

    /**
    * create navigation
    */
    private function _createNavi(){

        $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth==12?1:intval($this->currentMonth)+1;

        $nextYear = $this->currentMonth==12?intval($this->currentYear)+1:$this->currentYear;

        $preMonth = $this->currentMonth==1?12:intval($this->currentMonth)-1;

        $preYear = $this->currentMonth==1?intval($this->currentYear)-1:$this->currentYear;

        return
            '<div class="header">'.
                '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Zurück</a>'.
                    '<span class="title">'.date('m/Y',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
                '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf("%02d", $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Nächster</a>'.
            '</div>';
    }

    /**
    * create calendar week labels
    */
    private function _createLabels(){  

        $content='';

        foreach($this->dayLabels as $index=>$label){

            $content.='<li class="'.($label==6?'end title':'start title').' title">'.$label.'</li>';

        }

        return $content;
    }



    /**
    * calculate number of weeks in a particular month
    */
    private function _weeksInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

        if( null==($year) ) {
            $year =  date("Y",time()); 
        }

        if(null==($month)) {
            $month = date("m",time());
        }

        // find number of days in this month
        $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

        $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths%7==0?0:1) + intval($daysInMonths/7);

        $monthEndingDay= date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$daysInMonths));

        $monthStartDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));

        if($monthEndingDay<$monthStartDay){

            $numOfweeks++;

        }

        return $numOfweeks;
    }

    /**
    * calculate number of days in a particular month
    */
    private function _daysInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

        if(null==($year))
            $year =  date("Y",time()); 

        if(null==($month))
            $month = date("m",time());

        return date('t',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
    }

}
```

But the class is not loading. I get no output.

In php logfile is see the following:

```
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: year in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 33
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: month in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 35
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: year in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 37
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: year in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 41
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: month in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 47
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: month in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 51
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: con in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 136
[13-Sep-2018 09:59:15 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php:136
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php(78): Calendar->_showDay(1)
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\calendar.php(47): Calendar->show()
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info\class_calendar.php on line 136
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: Btw are you aware of the issues mixing markup, php and mysql? Think about separation of concerns... class Calendar is not there to render the calendar...

Comment: It is telling you what is wrong in that log, you have many undefined variables and your dbo is not initialised correctly.

Comment: BTW, `if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year']))` seems illogical as `isset` checks for `null` so if `$year` is `null` that condition will never pass and if it not equal to `null` (so `isset` is true) the `null` part of the condition will never pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Here is my customized code:

```
<?php

/**
*@author  Xu Ding
*@email   thedilab@gmail.com
*@website http://www.StarTutorial.com
**/

class Calendar {  

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(){     
        $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        $this->con = new mysqli("localhost","XXXX","XXXX","XXXX");
    }

    /********************* PROPERTY ********************/  
    private $dayLabels = array("Mo","Di","Mi","Do","Fr","Sa","So");
    private $currentYear = 0;    
    private $currentMonth = 0;     
    private $currentDay = 0;     
    private $currentDate = null;     
    private $daysInMonth = 0;     
    private $naviHref = null;

    /********************* PUBLIC **********************/  

    /**
    * print out the calendar
    */
    public function show() {
        $year  == null;

        $month == null;

        if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

            $year = $_GET['year'];

        }else if(null==$year){

            $year = date("Y",time());  

        }          

        if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

            $month = $_GET['month'];

        }else if(null==$month){

            $month = date("m",time());

        }                  

        $this->currentYear=$year;

        $this->currentMonth=$month;

        $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  

        $content='<div id="calendar">'.
                        '<div class="box">'.
                        $this->_createNavi().
                        '</div>'.
                        '<div class="box-content">'.
                                '<ul class="label">'.$this->_createLabels().'</ul>';   
                                $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     
                                $content.='<ul class="dates">';    

                                $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                                // Create weeks in a month
                                for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                                    //Create days in a week
                                    for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                        $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                                    }
                                }

                                $content.='</ul>';

                                $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     

                        $content.='</div>';

        $content.='</div>';
        return $content;   
    }

    /********************* PRIVATE **********************/ 
    /**
    * create the li element for ul
    */

    private function _showDay($cellNumber){

        if($this->currentDay==0){

            $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));

            if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

                $this->currentDay=1;

            }
        }



        if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

            $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

            $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

            $this->currentDay++;   

        }else{

            $this->currentDate = null;

            $cellContent=null;
        }

        //aktuellen tag rot markieren
        if(date("Y-m-d") == $this->currentDate) { $heute = "background-color: red;"; }

        //anzahl der kalendereinträge
        $offen = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS anzahl 
          FROM info_info 
          WHERE `datum` > '".$this->currentDate." 00:00:00' AND `datum` < '".$this->currentDate." 23:59:59'";       

        $resultoffen = $this->con->query($offen);
        if ($resultoffen->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $resultoffen->fetch_assoc()) {
            //$ungelesen = $row["anzahl"];
            if ($row["anzahl"] == "0") {
                $ungelesen = "";
            }
            else {
                //$ungelesen = $row['anzahl'];
                $eintrag = "background-color: green;";
            }
            }
        }

        //gib kalender zurück
        return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                ($cellContent==null?'mask':''). ' "style="'.$heute.$eintrag.'">'.$cellContent.$ungelesen.'</li>';
    }

    /**
    * create navigation
    */
    private function _createNavi(){

        $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth==12?1:intval($this->currentMonth)+1;

        $nextYear = $this->currentMonth==12?intval($this->currentYear)+1:$this->currentYear;

        $preMonth = $this->currentMonth==1?12:intval($this->currentMonth)-1;

        $preYear = $this->currentMonth==1?intval($this->currentYear)-1:$this->currentYear;

        return
            '<div class="header">'.
                '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Zurück</a>'.
                    '<span class="title">'.date('m/Y',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
                '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf("%02d", $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Nächster</a>'.
            '</div>';
    }

    /**
    * create calendar week labels
    */
    private function _createLabels(){  

        $content='';

        foreach($this->dayLabels as $index=>$label){

            $content.='<li class="'.($label==6?'end title':'start title').' title">'.$label.'</li>';

        }

        return $content;
    }



    /**
    * calculate number of weeks in a particular month
    */
    private function _weeksInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

        if( null==($year) ) {
            $year =  date("Y",time()); 
        }

        if(null==($month)) {
            $month = date("m",time());
        }

        // find number of days in this month
        $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

        $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths%7==0?0:1) + intval($daysInMonths/7);

        $monthEndingDay= date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$daysInMonths));

        $monthStartDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));

        if($monthEndingDay<$monthStartDay){

            $numOfweeks++;

        }

        return $numOfweeks;
    }

    /**
    * calculate number of days in a particular month
    */
    private function _daysInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

        if(null==($year))
            $year =  date("Y",time()); 

        if(null==($month))
            $month = date("m",time());

        return date('t',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
    }

}
```